# jquery on IE9 doesn't work: addclass from option/select

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

This is a mockup version of a dashboard that is not functioning properly in IE9 or IE10. It works perfectly in Chrome, Firefox, and the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y2adT/) I set up for it during testing. When you select "controls" at the top, then select "custom date range" from the "custom date range" dropdown, as you can see in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y2adT/) the calendar appears to the right. Only in IE9 and IE10 does this not work. Any suggestions to fix this would be greatly appreciated. I have tried switching it from a .click to a .change; and tried different scenarios using blur or focus as well. I'm pretty sure this is the suspect code (lines 103-114 in the jsfiddle):

```
    range.css({
        left: area.outerWidth(true) - 1
    })
    select.change(function () {
        var options = select.find('option').filter('[selected]');
        if (options.hasClass('rangeDate')) {
            jcfSelect.showDropdown();
            range.addClass('dropActive').show();
        } else {
            range.removeClass('dropActive').hide();
        }
    });
```

Thanks in advance!